# Anonymous block acting like static block

Tags: java

I have a simple code as following :

```
class TempClass 
{  
    {    
        System.out.println("inside static...");
    }

    TempClass()
    {
        System.out.println("inside constructor...");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new TempClass();
    }
}
```

It shows output as : 
inside static...
inside constructor...

But when i comment the instance creation line, it shows blank output.
So its acting as a static block whenever there is a call to constructor.
Does it means writing static is not mandatory (when class is instantiated) ?

Anyone knows anything about this behavior ?

Comment: If it were a static block it would show its output even without instantiating the class since you load it to call main. You assumption is double-false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{
      System.out.println("inside static...");
}
```

... is not a `static` block, it's an instance block.

```
static {
      System.out.println("inside static...");
}
```

... would be a `static` block.

Comment: Thanks @Mena! 
yes i knew its not static block - but i also didnt know its an initialiser block.

Answer (score 6):

```
{
  System.out.println("inside static...");
}
```

is **not** a **static block** , instead its an **instance block** and it gets translated to something like this

```
class TempClass
{  
    TempClass()
    {
        {

           System.out.println("inside static...");
        }
        System.out.println("inside constructor...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not `static block`.
A blocks without `static` key word is called`instance blocks` or `initializer blocks`.
The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.
Refer java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

> Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:

In java There are two alternatives to using a constructor to initialize instance variables: initializer blocks and final methods.
using *initializer blocks*

```
class Whatever {
   private int myVar ;
   {
     // initialization code goes here
      myvar = 10;
   }
}
```

using *final methods.*

```
class Whatever {
  private int myVar = initializeInstanceVariable();

  protected final int initializeInstanceVariable() {

    // initialization code goes here
    return 10;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Actually there isn't any `static` block in your code. If it is there, you can run and get the out put without instantiating